# Are there known policy settings causing unexpectedly terminated RDP sessions to be logged off - Event 551

Tags: windows, rdp, client-server

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383015(VS.85).aspx states

> When a user's session is unexpectedly terminated by a network or client failure, the user is disconnected but not logged off.

But since we got a new system administrator who installed some policy to terminate disconnected sessions after some hours, I never again could reconnect to to an unexpectedly terminated session (usually VPN problem)

I found the following [link](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1570259&page=2) which shows a similat scenario.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably configured to log-off sessions as soon as they're disconnected (or a very short time later).

Something like `Set time limit for disconnected sessions = 0`